# Как мне запустить Activity из другого класса?

Tags: java, android, activity, android-intent

Есть класс RunActivityClass, в нем метод startSelectedActivity, который должен запустить Activity

```
public class RunActivityClass {
     public void startSelectedActivity {
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TextActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
     {
{
```

И есть MainActivity, где создается объект типа RunActivityClass и вызывается метод startActivity

```
RunActivityClass runActivityClass = new RunActivityClass();
runActivityClass.startSelectedAсtivity();
```

Вопрос первый, как мне изменить startSelectedAсtivity(), чтобы Activity запускалось?

И второй вопрос? Как лучше сделать общую функцию, которая бы по параметру запускала ту или иную Activity? Подходит ли выбранный мной метод, когда я каждый раз создаю объект и потом вызываю необходимую функцию?

Comment: Самым логичным будет не создавать какие то классы запуска активити, а запускать их напрямую, через интент, каждый раз, когда требуется переход. Используя отдельный класс вы ничего не выиграете и даже потеряете в расходе памяти, так как будет создан дополнителный (и не нужный) объект класса. Даже на обращение к вашему классу и на прямой вызов уходит примерно равное количество строк, так что и тут нет никакой выгоды.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше всего сделать так

```
public class TextActivity {
     public static void start(Context context) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, TextActivity.class);
         context.startActivity(intent);
     }
     //...
}

//запуск из MainActivity
TextActivity.start(this);
```

То есть в каждом activity создаем статический метод для запуска.
Писать отдельный класс для управления запусками activity не стоит.

Comment: По поводу этого вопроса: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/494121/181472. Вы оставили тревогу, что он не относится к [tag:android]. В данном случае незачем обращаться к модератору. Вы можете самостоятельно предложить правку: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/494121/edit

Answer (score 0):

1. Ваш ко не скомпилируется, т.к. вы не указали аргументы методу `startSelectedActivity`.
2. Для запуска активити нужен `Context`, поэтому его следует передать в метод `startSelectedActivity`
3. Можно сделать по разному. Почти бесконечным кол-вом способов. Всё зависит от конкретной ситуации. Можете, например, кроме `Context` передать в аргументах метода нужный класс (класс активити для запуска)
4. Я бы сделал этот метод просто статическим. Так вам не надо бует создавать вручную объект класса.