# Обращение к объекту из другого класса

Tags: java

Есть 3 класса внутри одного пакета:

1. Осуществляет посылку запроса на авторизацию;
2. Получает ответ;
3. Работает с ответом.

Проблема в том, что не понимаю, как получить ссылку на объект, который создается в первом классе из 3-его.

Class1.java - Запрос авторизации
    UserData userData;

```
public void calcLogin(){
ht.call(SOAP_ACTION + methodname, envelope, header);
SoapObject resultsString = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
userData.setDataStore("ID", resultsString.getProperty(0).toString()) 
}
```

Я хочу получить результат выполнения действия в 3-ем классе.

class3.java

```
class UserData {
static Map<String,String> dataStore = new HashMap<String,String>();
}
public void setDataStore(String a1, String a2){
dataStore.put(a1,a2);
}
```

Но я не вижу такого объекта. Получается, что его нет в памяти. Подскажите, куда копать и на что обратить внимание.

Comment: Добавьте код из ваших трёх классов.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Переменная не будет видна, если она объявлена внутри метода, так как на нее не существует жесткой ссылки. Иными словами, после выполнения метода переменная действительно стирается из памяти (ну, с учетом особенностей работы сборщика мусора).

Чтобы увидеть переменную, необязательно объявлять ее статичной, достаточно в самом начале класса, в блоке описания переменных, объявить ее как protected (видимость внутри пакета) или public (общая видимость).

Вроде того:

```
class Class1{
    protected UserData ud1; 
    protected static UserData ud2;

    public void someMethod(){
          UserData ud3;
    }
}
```

Здесь переменная ud1 будет видна всем классам внутри пакета через экземпляр класса Class1 (например, new Class1().ud1) - и, соответственно, будет разная для каждого экземпляра класса.

Статичная переменная ud2 - это переменная, одинаковая для всех экземпляров класса. Будет доступна для всех классов внутри пакета через Class1.ud2 . Вряд ли это то, что вам нужно.

Ну а третья переменная ud3 отойдет сборщику мусора после выполнения метода.

Answer (score 2):

Честно говоря, я не понял чего именно вы хотите. Но если я подумал в правильном направлении, то примерный код:

```
class Class1 {
    ...
    public UserData getUd1() {
        return ud1;
    }
    ...
}

class Class3 {
    ...
    private UserData ud1;
    ...
    public void setUd1(UserData ud1) {
        this.ud1 = ud1;
    }
    ...
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    Class3 class3 = new Class3();

    class3.setUd1(class1.getUd1());
}
```

Comment: Я всего лишь хочу работать с данными, которые запишутся в память после выполнении метода в классе1. И потом при обращении из класса2, класса3 и т.д. я хочу получать эти данные. Поэтому пришлось объявить переменную в классе 2 статичной. Наверно, это не камильфо, но других вариантов я пока не нашел. Спасибо!

Comment: @Иван Вовк, пожалуйста, но, судя по всему, я вам ничем не помог. Думаю, если бы вы выложили код классов с комментариями (указывая где и что вы хотите сделать и получить), то нам было бы проще разобраться и дать правильный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

При создании объекта `Сlass3.java` нужно в него как-то передать объект

```
UserData ud1 = new UserData();
```

Т.к. `ud1` это локальная переменная в `Class1.java` и видна только в той функции, где ее создали. После этого получите доступ ко всем свойствам `ud1` включая и `ud1.getID()`

З.Ы. Пройдитесь по теории [области видимости в java](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: Не очень понял ваше объяснение! Объект-то создать не проблема в Class3, проблема в получении ссылки на уже созданный объект (ud1) в Class1. Грубо говоря, как получить объект, который еще в памяти (или нет???) из другого класса? Зону видимости переменных изучил - моя переменная видна в пределах пакета.

Comment: Код, который вы указали - это часть функции и область видимости локальной переменной (ud1) только эта функция! Что бы увидеть эту переменную в объекте другого класса ее нужно туда как то передать.

Comment: Нет, если переменная статичная, я могу обратиться к ней после выполнения метода из класса1, класса3, и т.д. Вот я и ищу способ как сделать так чтобы не делать эти данные статичными.

Comment: Код в вопросе весь переиначен, с того момента как я отвечал. Статичные поля, блоки - это "вонючий код" (code smell), который таит в себе потенциальные баги, которые трудно будет найти, делает рефакторинг и тестирование трудным.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

Class1:

```
public final class Class1 {

//Возвращает версию Android
public static String getmVersRelease() {
    String mVersRelease = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
    return mVersRelease;
}
//Версия SDK
public static int getmVersSdk() {
    int mVersionSdk = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    return mVersionSdk;
}
}
```

Class2:

```
import static com.example.dddddd.testTest.Class1.getmVersRelease;
import static com.example.dddddd.testTest.Class1.getmVersSdk;
```

Далее уже используем ваши переменные mVersRelease и mVersionSdk в этом классе...

Answer (score 0):

Можно вызвать объект, созданный в другом классе, если этот объект создать внутри статического метода. Я делал так:
В основном классе Main вызов такой:

```
User user = User.deserialize();
```

А в классе User был такой метод:

```
public static User deserialize() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("saveFile.sf");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    User restoredUser = (User) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    return restoredUser;
}
```

Попросту говоря, я вернул объект restoredUser вызывающему объекту user.